# Set default value in <mat-select> based on boolean condition for a list

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I am using mat-select for dropdown and the data I am getting from the server is a List of objects. And the dropdown is for a List in each object. Sample data looks like below

```json
[
{
    "id": 16902488,
    "email": "",
    "email_domain": "",
    "first_name": null,
    "last_name": null,
    "address_line_1": null,
    "address_city": null,
    "address_state": null,
    "address_postal": null,
    "clicked_at": "2021-05-22T03:53:36.000Z",
    "landing_page_url": "",
    "landing_page_domain": "",
    "created_at": "2021-05-22T04:08:52.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-05-22T04:08:52.000Z",
    "page_title": "",
    "referrer": null,
    "status": null,
    "templateNames": [
      {
        "id": 1011,
        "productId": 1012,
        "accountId": 3,
        "templateName": "fgdgf",
        "description": "dgfdg",
        "emailSubject": "sgrg",
        "templateHTML": "grfggr",
        "productName": "wef",
        "from": "tegwttg",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      {
        "id": 1013,
        "productId": 1012,
        "accountId": 1006,
        "templateName": "fgdgf",
        "description": "dgfdg",
        "emailSubject": "sgrg",
        "templateHTML": "",
        "productName": "wef",
        "from": "tegwttg",
        "isDefault": false
      },
      {
        "id": 1015,
        "productId": 1012,
        "accountId": 3,
        "templateName": "fgdgf",
        "description": "dgfdg",
        "emailSubject": "sgrg",
        "templateHTML": "",
        "productName": "wef",
        "from": "tegwttg",
        "isDefault": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have created dropdown for **templateNames** and I am able to get the values in the droopdown. But I want to set default value for the dropdown based on if **isDefault** value is true or false in each of the templatenames.Below is the code I have written.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="TEMPLATE">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> TEMPLATE
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <mat-select [value]='???????' (selectionChange)="addTemplateToLead($event)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let template of element.templateNames" [value]="template">
                {{template.templateName}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official doc](https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples#select-initial-value) provides an example of a selection with an initial value. There should be a two-way binding on the `value` property:

```html
<mat-select [multiple]="true" [(value)]="selections">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let template of templates" [value]="template">
    {{template.templateName}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

The `selections` property of the component should be initialized with the selections to set. Here is a simplified version of the component:

```js
export class AppComponent {

  templates = [
    {
      id: 1011,
      templateName: 'fgdgf1',
      isDefault: true
    },
    {
      id: 1013,
      templateName: 'fgdgf2',
      isDefault: false
    },
    {
      id: 1015,
      templateName: 'fgdgf3',
      isDefault: true
    }
  ];

  selections: Array<any>;

  constructor() {
    this.selections = this.templates.filter((t: any) => !!t.isDefault);
  }

}
```

The `selections` property contains the values that are currently selected. It is initialized with the array of templates that have `isDefault` = `true`. In the real component, this value should be initialized just after the parent object of the `templates` is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to initialize mat-select.
There are many ways to do this, and one way is to use formControl, as shown in the example below

html:

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>TEMPLATE</mat-label>
    <mat-select [formControl]="selected">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let template of item.templateNames" [value]="template">
                {{template.templateName}}
            </mat-option>
        </ng-container>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

ts:

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'selectbox';
    constructor() { }
    ngOnInit() {
        const indexData = this.data.findIndex(d => d.id == 16902488); // 16902488 dynamic
        const indexTemplateNames = this.data[indexData].templateNames.findIndex(d => d.isDefault == true);
        this.selected.setValue(this.data[indexData].templateNames[indexTemplateNames]);

    }
    selected = new FormControl(null);

    data = [
        {
            "id": 16902488,
            "email": "",
            "email_domain": "",
            "first_name": null,
            "last_name": null,
            "address_line_1": null,
            "address_city": null,
            "address_state": null,
            "address_postal": null,
            "clicked_at": "2021-05-22T03:53:36.000Z",
            "landing_page_url": "",
            "landing_page_domain": "",
            "created_at": "2021-05-22T04:08:52.000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-05-22T04:08:52.000Z",
            "page_title": "",
            "referrer": null,
            "status": null,
            "templateNames": [
                {
                    "id": 1011,
                    "productId": 1012,
                    "accountId": 3,
                    "templateName": "fgdgf",
                    "description": "dgfdg",
                    "emailSubject": "sgrg",
                    "templateHTML": "grfggr",
                    "productName": "wef",
                    "from": "tegwttg",
                    "isDefault": true
                },
                {
                    "id": 1013,
                    "productId": 1012,
                    "accountId": 1006,
                    "templateName": "fgdgf",
                    "description": "dgfdg",
                    "emailSubject": "sgrg",
                    "templateHTML": "",
                    "productName": "wef",
                    "from": "tegwttg",
                    "isDefault": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 1015,
                    "productId": 1012,
                    "accountId": 3,
                    "templateName": "fgdgf",
                    "description": "dgfdg",
                    "emailSubject": "sgrg",
                    "templateHTML": "",
                    "productName": "wef",
                    "from": "tegwttg",
                    "isDefault": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but the “data” you have initialised should be an Array. In that case this won’t work.

Comment: I edited the answer, I hope the answer is correct